# if I delete an APK from the Play developer console, is it still available for download until I hit publish?

Tags: android, apk, google-play

When uploading an updated APK to my game on the new Play store developer console, I get red klaxons and badness because it conflicts with the previous uploaded version. I guess I have to press the Archive button next to the previous APK, but that's scary.

Can someone confirm that an end user won't actually see any changes until I hit the Publish button? My app isn't going to be removed from sale for even a few minutes?

EDIT: originally mentioned Delete, when I meant Archive

UPDATE: I bit the bullet and hit Archive yesterday. Have not yet hit Publish on the new APKs. My Play Store page now claims the game was updated yesterday. Hold me, I'm scared.

Comment: As far as I remember, there's also an "archive APK" functionality, which I'd prefer. You may need to switch to _extended view_ or so, I don't recall exactly.

Comment: Yes I'm in advanced view of the v2 console. It's a game so I've got multiple APKs for each version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is first valid when you publish. Just been playing around with my own apks to test it.
If you make a wrong configuration, like archieving the newest apk version, it will disable the publish button, so you cant publish.

It only creates a draft, when you archive. The draft is first valid on publish.

Comment: Super that's what I wanted to be absolutely sure of.

Comment: so I hit Archive... and the APK jumped to the PREVIOUS APKs section. No publish button necessary. I could restore it easily but still a little scared that it was there!

Comment: ...did that yesterday, have not yet hit publish, and my play store page is claiming the game has been updated yesterday. still seems available for download though. so far!

Comment: Yeah this is absolutely fine. Archive away. Nothing visible to the store user until you hit Publish with a new APK.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delete published files, so if you see "delete" button it is just for uploaded **unpublished** APK. You can safely wipe it out as it's just local change

Comment: Sorry my mistake - I meant the Archive button next to the currently-active APKs. If I hit that, will people still see the app in the store until I hit Publish?

Answer (score -1):

When you want to make app update in play store you have to:
1. Increase versioncode in androidmanifest.xml
2. Upload apk to playstore
3. Publish apk

Note: Apk which is "published" is available for users to download.

Comment: not true - you can have multiple APKs published if targeting different texture compressions.